# Add href to txthtml column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

- I am binding the values from Sql DB to dynamic html table.And it
  contains one constant columun(Action) which should contain adress of
  particular portal for all rows of the html table.
- With below code I am finding no luck to assign href to `<td>`

Can any one help me how can I solove this

```
txtHTML = txtHTML + "<td>";
txtHTML = txtHTML + <a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Action</a>+ "</a>";
txtHTML = txtHTML + "</td>";
```

Comment: `txtHTML + '<a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Action</a>';`

Comment: it has to be the opposite @GuruprasadRao, for a proper standard

Comment: `txtHTML = txtHTML + "<a href='http://www.w3schools.com'>Action</a>";`

Comment: standard is using `" "` for `html attribute values`. jquery can manage with `' '`

Comment: I made you an example here:https://jsfiddle.net/od6jmcae/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just the matter of the usage of `"` and `'` in your code as a string

```
txtHTML = txtHTML + "<td>";
txtHTML = txtHTML + "<a href='http://www.w3schools.com'>Action</a>";
txtHTML = txtHTML + "</td>";
```

This above code will help you!